# What's the architecture of the lstm engine in Tesseract 4+ OCR?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have found that the  model used in Tesseract 4+ LSTM is the same used in OCROpus the CLSTM project, available here: https://github.com/tmbdev/clstm.

in the link below I found the info about the lstm model but **I can not draw the architecture of the model from it** .
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tmbdev/clstm/blob/master/misc/clstm-tests.ipynb

**info of the lstm model on the CLSTM project :**

```
.Stacked: 0.000100 0.900000 11 13
.Stacked.Parallel: 0.000100 0.900000 11 40
.Stacked.Parallel.NPLSTM_SigmoidTanhTanh: 0.000100 0.900000 11 20
.Stacked.Parallel.Reversed: 0.000100 0.900000 11 20
.Stacked.Parallel.Reversed.NPLSTM_SigmoidTanhTanh: 0.000100 0.900000 11 20
.Stacked.SoftmaxLayer: 0.000100 0.900000 40 13
```